# add context, for form in odoo 13. With js

Tags: javascript, python, xml, odoo, datacontext

I tried (for several days) to pass the context from my js view to my xml field.

The JavaScript function has a default create button

[image]

I need it to open a form with a value in the field, as in the screenshot:

[image]

I need to add context in js.

my xml code for form:

```
<field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Student">
                <header>
                    <button name="button_done" string="Done" class="oe_highlight" type="object"/>
                    <button name="button_reset" string="Reset to Draft" states="done,cancel"
                            class="oe_highlight" type="object"/>
                    <button name="button_cancel" string="Cancel" type="object"/>
                    <field name="state" widget="statusbar" statusbar_visible="draft,done"/>
                </header>
                <sheet>
                    <field name="photo" widget="image" class="oe_left oe_avatar" />
                    <div class="oe_title">
                        <h3>
                            <field name="name"/>
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                    <group>
                        <group>
                            <field name="age"/>
                            <field name="gender"/>
                        </group>
                        <group>
                            <field name="student_dob"/>
                            <field name="student_blood_group"/>
                            <field name="nationality"/>
                        </group>
                    </group>
                </sheet>
```

my js code:

```
odoo.define('invoice.action_button', function (require) {
"use strict";
var core = require('web.core');
var ListController = require('web.ListController');
var rpc = require('web.rpc');
var session = require('web.session');
var _t = core._t;
ListController.include({

    dispatch_to_new_action: function() {
        this.do_action({
            context: {'default_gender': 'Male'},
        });
        console.log('hello')
    },

   renderButtons: function($node) {
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
            var btnsDiv =  this.$buttons;
            if (this.$buttons) {
                var createBtn = this.$buttons.find('.o_list_button_add')
            }
```

python code for feild:

```
    gender = fields.Selection(
    [('male', 'Male'), ('female', 'Female'), ('others', 'Others')],
    string='Gender')
```

Comment: why don't you use odoo default orm method?

Comment: @DipenShah. I redid the create button, added a dropdown and now the context depends on the name of the button

Comment: from your description, you have a selection(dropdown) on your form and you want to achieve auto-set while click on create button male/female/other should be default set? that you want?

Comment: @DipenShah. Yes, you're right.

Comment: Than used the odoo 'def default_get' methods which can help to set the default value while creating the record.

Comment: @DipenShah. I do not understand what do you mean. I want to use js to open a form with an already set value and that’s it. Could you give a hint? I'm new to odoo.

Answer (score 0):

In your python code add the default option no need to use JS

```
gender = fields.Selection([
    ('male', 'Male'), 
    ('female', 'Female'), 
    ('others', 'Others')
], string='Gender', default='male')
```